# AutomationElement get real Type

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, ui-automation

How do I get the real `Type` of `AutomationElement` (for example `TextEdit` and so on)? `GetType()` returns `System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement`.

Comment: Try element.Current.ClassName ? - It only works for some frameworks, though; eg. returns SysListView32 for Win32 listviews. It's up to each framework to decide how to use this, and I don't think WPF exposes anything useful here.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Type of automation element through `AutomationElement.Current.ControlType` property.

```
ControlType controlType = AutomationElement.Current.ControlType;
```

For more info see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationelementinformation.controltype.aspx).

Comment: And it returns System.Windows.Automation.ControlType.... instead of DevExpress's TextEdit...

Comment: @ArtemMakarov I really hope this isn't a problem for you anymore. How ever i just had the same problem. This is how i got the correct type: `AutomationElement.Current.ControlType.ProgrammaticName`

Answer (score 0):

I tried and found following worked:

```
DirectCast(<AutoElementName>.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty), ControlType).LocalizedControlType
```